# Detect which checkbox is unchecked in my recyclerview kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I have the following poll project with affirmative and negative answers, but I am having problems, when I want to detect that checkboxes are unchecked in my recylcerview , I want to achieve this with the intention of launching an alert to the user that there are unanswered questions and thus avoid blank responses.

Here is my adapter answers

**class adaptadorpreguntas**

`

```
class adaptadorpreguntas(
    private val context : Context,
    private val listpreguntaspreuso: ArrayList<epreguntas2>
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<adaptadorpreguntas.PreguntasViewHolder>() {
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(
        parent: ViewGroup,
        viewType: Int
    ): PreguntasViewHolder {
        val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context)
        return PreguntasViewHolder(
            layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_estructura_preguntas, parent, false)
        )
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: PreguntasViewHolder, position: Int) {

        val item = listpreguntaspreuso[position]
        holder.render(item)
        holder.displayChecked(item.answer)

    }
    override fun getItemCount(): Int = listpreguntaspreuso.size





    inner class PreguntasViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
        val binding = ActivityEstructuraPreguntasBinding.bind(view)
        private val idpregunta = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.txtidpregunta)
        private val numeropregunta = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.txtnumeropregunta)
        private val pregunta = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.txtpreguntas)
        private val imgestado = view.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.icosemaforo)
        private val subitems = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.txtsubitem)
        var categoria: String = ""
        var itemp : String = ""
        var indicador : String = ""
        var aplicana : String = ""
        //FUNCIONES
        fun render (epreguntas: epreguntas2){
            idpregunta.text = epreguntas.id_pregunta
            categoria = epreguntas.IDCATEGORIA
            itemp = epreguntas.ITEM
            subitems.text = epreguntas.SUBITEM
            numeropregunta.text = epreguntas.ITEM
            pregunta.text = epreguntas.pregunta
            indicador = epreguntas.INDICADOR
            aplicana = epreguntas.APLICANA
            Glide.with(imgestado.context).load(epreguntas.icono_estado).into(imgestado)


        }


        private val checkboxAnswers = mapOf(
            binding.chbksi2 to Answer.SI,
            binding.chbkno to Answer.NO,
            binding.chbkna2 to Answer.NA,


        )
        init {
            // establecer el oyente en todas las casillas de verificación
            checkboxAnswers.keys.forEach { checkbox ->
                checkbox.setOnClickListener { handleCheckboxClick(checkbox) }
                //checkbox.setOnClickListener { valorcheck(checkbox) }
            }
        }

        // Una función que maneja todas las casillas de verificación
        private fun handleCheckboxClick(checkbox: CheckBox) {

            // obtener el elemento para la posición que muestra el VH
            val item = listpreguntaspreuso[adapterPosition]

            // actualice el estado marcado del elemento con la respuesta asociada con esta casilla de verificación
            // Si solo se ha -desmarcado-, eso significa que no hay nada marcado
            checkboxAnswers[checkbox]?.let { answer ->
                item.answer = if (!checkbox.isChecked) null

                else answer
                // recuerde notificar al adaptador (para que pueda volver a mostrar y desmarcar cualquier otra casilla)
                notifyItemChanged(adapterPosition)
            }
        }

        fun displayChecked(answer: Answer?) {
            // establecer el estado marcado para todas las casillas, verificado si coincide con la respuesta
            // y desmarcado de lo contrario.
            // Establecer cada cuadro de cualquier manera borra cualquier estado anterior del último elemento mostrado
            checkboxAnswers.forEach { (checkbox, answerType) ->
                checkbox.isChecked = answerType == answer
            }
        }
        fun displayAnswers(answers: Collection<Answer>) {
            // iterar sobre cada par de casilla de verificación/respuesta, ocultando o mostrando según corresponda
            checkboxAnswers.forEach { (checkbox, answerType) ->
                checkbox.visibility = if (answerType in answers) View.VISIBLE else View.GONE
            }
        }

    }
}
```

`

I tried the following code to detect that checkbox is unchecked and assign a value to the validation variable, I will call this validation **variable **in my preuse activity to then go through the list and compare if it is equal to the assigned text or value that launches an alert and so on warn the user that there are unmarked questions.

`

```
when{
    !holder.binding.chbksi2.isChecked && !holder.binding.chbkno.isChecked ->{
        listpreguntaspreuso.get(position).validacion = "no"
    }
}
```

`

**Activity preuse**

`

```
private fun validacion_check(){
    var validacioness: String = ""
    for(ubicacion in listado2.indices){

        validacioness=   listado2[ubicacion].validacion

    }
    if(validacioness == "no") {
        Toast.makeText(this@listapreuso, "Hay preguntas sin marcar",Toast.LENGTH_LONG
        ).show()
    } else {
        llamaraldialogo()
    }


}
```

`
[my survey](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rXDqk.png)

Comment: RecyclerViews viewholders are volatile and reusable and as such are not a place to hold any state. You have to modify your questions array so they can store users current answer (or hold separate array of answers, that's up to you), then it's a matter of iterating over them. Any attempt to iterate over viewholders will fail because recyclerview by design will not lay out viewholder for all list items at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not realize that the solution was in front of my eyes, thanks to all, attached solution.

**I applied this in my pre-use activity.**

```
 private fun validacion_check(){
    var validacioness: String = ""
    for(ubicacion in listado2.indices){

        if (listado2[ubicacion].valorcheck == "error" && validacioness == ""){
            validacioness = "error"
        }

    }
    Toast.makeText(this@listapreuso, " : {$validacioness}",Toast.LENGTH_LONG
    ).show()
    if(validacioness == "error") {
        Toast.makeText(this@listapreuso, "Hay preguntas sin marcar",Toast.LENGTH_LONG
        ).show()
    } else {
        llamaraldialogo()
    }
}
```